# Converting bitmap pixels as byte array fails

Tags: c#, bitmap, arrays, converters

I have to convert the pixels of a bitmap to short array. Therefore I want to:

- get the bytes
- convert the bytes to short

This is my source to get the bytes:

```
 public byte[] BitmapToByte(Bitmap source)
 {
     using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         source.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
         return memoryStream.ToArray();
     }
 }
```

This is not returning the expected results. Is there another way to convert the data?

Comment: `512 x 512 x 4 = 1048576` so where is the missing bytes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please explain your problem properly. *"I'm missing bytes"* is not something that can be solved. What data do you expect, and what do you see?

`Bitmap.Save()` will return the data according to the specified format, which in all cases contains more than just the pixel data (headers describing width and height, color / palette data, and so on). If you just want an array of pixel data, you'd better look at [`Bimap.LockBits()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx):

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\fakePhoto.jpg");

// Lock the bitmap's bits.  
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

// Get the address of the first line.
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

// Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
int bytes  = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

// Copy the RGB values into the array.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
```

Now the `rgbValues` array contains all pixels from the source bitmap, using three bytes per pixel. I don't know why you want an array of shorts, but you must be able to figure that out from here.

Comment: @leppie me neither, but [_" If the stride is positive, the bitmap is top-down. If the stride is negative, the bitmap is bottom-up."_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride.aspx).

Comment: I have to work with integer values now but in the end there is no difference.thanks